# Insert background image for Web content portlet in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-ide

I am developing a portlet using web content portlet. I would like to give a background image to it. There is an option to put background color in Look and Feel option, but:

- What if I wish to add a background image to it?
- And how do I do it since the image will have to be uploaded on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Advance Styling tab under look and feel, and provide background-image css attribute to portlet. You can put background image in theme or upload it in document and library portlet and provide uri of image in css accordingly.